# VirtualBoxでネットワークのアダプター2 ~ アダプター4を選択できない

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBoxの設定→ネットワークタブからアダプター2〜アダプター4をクリックできません。

OSはシャットダウンしているのですが、なぜクリックできないのでしょうか。
何かご教示いただけることがあれば、よろしくお願いします

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

仮想環境の「保存状態を破棄」をすると選択することができました。